# Understanding Integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is a question coming from a Math newb.
When I learn something I try to connect it to what I already know, so please bear with me.

I know how to calculate integrals, but I never really understood what they mean, until I read [this](https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-calculus-analogy-integrals-as-multiplication/) and felt like it was a really good explanation. So I tried to test the hypothesis with some examples.

When you have a static function like

$$f(x) = 2$$

And you make a definite integration, it's ok:

$$\int_0^32\space dx = 2  \cdot 3- 2 \cdot 0 = 6$$

That's basically like saying 3 $\cdot$ y, with y behaving according to $y = 2$. But as soon as I try to test what he said with a variable, e.g.: $$f(x) = 2x$$

$$\int_0^3 2x\space dx= \frac{2 \cdot 3^2}{2} - \frac{2 \cdot 0^2}{2} = 9$$

However I expected it to be like $3 \cdot y$, with $y$ behaving according to $y = 2$.
In the end I thought, what I was actually thinking of was $\sum$, but I still don't really get what integration (a/o differentiation) means.

I know when I calculate the area under the function curve, but *what does that mean*?
Let's think only in positive integer values. I have an unlimited amount of apple baskets. The first one will have two apples, the second one will have four apples, the one after that 6, etc.
So that function would be:

$$\operatorname{How many apples do I have after basket}(x) = 2x$$

Then what would the value of the definite integral between 0 and 3 (which is $9$) imply?

Comment: If the function is non-negative in an interval $[a,b]$, then the integral over the function from $a$ to $b$ is equal to the area the function encloses with the $x$-axis within this interval, in the case, the function is non-positive, the integral is the negative of that area. In general, an integral sums up areas (taking negative values, where $f(x)<0$).

Comment: The definition of (Riemann) integration relies on the definition of the Riemann sum.  Do you understand that you can approximate the area under any piecewise continuous curve by finding the areas of certain well-chosen rectangles?

Comment: Yes, I know. Does that mean that integration only makes sense with real numbers? Also, what does the area under a continuous curve mean for the function itself? (I know I may sound like a child at this point, but I really want to grasp the concept of an integral) E.g. I know that the differentiation of the the speed is acceleration, which indicates, that the integration of acceleration is speed. Is that by accident?

Comment: "The first one will have two apples, the second one will have four apples,  the one after that 8 etc." I think you mean 6 rather than 8. In your example the integral between $0$ and $3$ is the total number of apples in the first three baskets (assuming a step function rather than a straight line) because then it just the sum $2(1)+2(2)+2(3)=14$.

Comment: You can certainly define integration on other number systems than real numbers (you'll see how to do it with complex numbers when you take a course on complex analysis), but you have to understand integrals of real-valued functions before you can move on to more complicated spaces.  As for what integration *means*, it depends.  Intuitively integration is essentially adding up infinitely many infinitesimally small things.  The result might be area or volume or speed or arc length or energy or probability or ...

Comment: @smcc But the integral is $9$, not $14$, and the total numbers would be $12$, not $14$. I don't quite understand where you got that $14$ from.

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant $12$. I was not using the function $2x$ for but a step function that is $2$ for $x\in[0,1]$, $4$ for $x\in(1,2]$ and $6$ for $x\in(2,3]$. Try drawing it.

Comment: In fact the integral of the step function you described, from $0$ to $3$, is exactly $12$, just as you thought. When you have the function $2x$ on the real numbers, its values are almost all a little smaller than the step-function values, so its integral comes out smaller as well.

Comment: @DavidK Is there some algorithm to calculate the integral of a step function? I can see it when I draw it, like smcc suggested, but I wonder if I can somehow prove it.

Comment: You can make a Riemann sum of the step function. Or use the fact that the function is constant within $[0,1]$ to integrate that subinterval, similarly for $(1,2]$ and $(2,3]$, and use the fact $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx + \int_b^c f(x)\,dx = \int_a^c f(x)\,dx$ a couple of times to get the integral over the whole interval $[0,3]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your confusion stems from a misunderstanding of how summations relate to integrals. Think of an integral as the limit of a Riemann Sum, or $Lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \Sigma f(x)\Delta x$. Let's think for a second about how we derive this.

We know an integral is the area under a curve. But how can we calculate this without calculus? Well, we can start with an approximation. Take the function $f(x) = x^3$, for example, on the interval 0 to 3. One way to begin approximating this is to use a series of boxes that fit under the curve, since we can easily calculate the area of a box. Starting with 4 boxes, our approximation would, graphically, look something like this:

[image]

And we could get are approximate integral by taking the sum of the areas of the rectangles. Using the simple $area = h * w$ formula and the graph, we can see that the height of any one rectangle is the function value at the rectangle's leftmost point, and the width of a rectangle is a constant .5. This is nice, and all, but there is a lot of area under the curve that the rectangles don't 'cover'. One way to 'cover' more area, and get a better approximation, is to use slimmer rectangles:

[image]

Now, there is much less area that is not 'covered' by the rectangles under the curve, which will result in a better approximation. So if error decreases as we make the rectangles slimmer, what happens if we make the rectangles *infinitely* slim? The error would go to 0, and we would get our perfect amount of area under the curve. Abusing notation for a second, we can think of this as $Lim_{width\rightarrow 0} \Sigma height * width$, or, a sum of infinitely slim rectangles under the curve. Since height is the function value at the leftmost point of the rectangle, and width is just a distance along the x axis, we can substitute our variables and get the integral formula we began with,  $Lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \Sigma f(x)\Delta x$

The reason that your how many apples question fails is that your apple 'function' is not continuous. Imagine graphing your apple function, which is defined only on the positive integers. It would only be a series of points at x=1, 2, 3, etc... and not a smooth curve. What the integral is calculating is the area under the smooth curve defined on all real numbers within your bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is very true. You are adding apples up. For a non-wild function  $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ means adding up (infinitely many) values $f(x)$. But why does it become finite? Because each value $f(x)$ only occupies the single point $x$ on the interval $[a,b]$. So, it is adding up very many values but each value being multiplied by an almost zero segment. Thus, it is the interplay of these that allows for the final result to become finite number.

A second interpretation: Imagine a function that is $1$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$, is $5$ from $x=2$ to $x=7$. What is a fair average for this function? Is it $\frac{1+5}{2}$ because those are the only values $f$ takes on? I don't think it will be fair. Because $f$ tries "hard" to be $5$ on a longer interval. If you drive at $10$ mph for $30$ minutes and then continue at $70$ mph for 3 hours, will your average speed be $50$?! Of course not. So, to define a nice average, you must take into account the bandwidth, the segment, the portion where $f$ takes on a certain value. In integrating $f(x)$ over $[a,b]$ you add up values of $f$ taking into account "how much $x$-space" that value of $f$ occupies.

Note to mathematicians: This way of looking at $\int f$ is closer to Lebesgue integral than to Riemann. One wonders why the latter was invented first!